# How to render a link to the newform.aspx in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created a webpart that render the content of a list using the DetailList component. 
Now I want to create a link to the NewForm.aspx so when a user click on it get sended to the new item form.

The link needs to be dynamic. The webpart can be used with diferent lists so I can´t hardcode the link.

How can I do it?

Best regards,
Americo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pnpJs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts) to get list form url, sample code for your reference.

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList3").forms.select().filter("FormType eq 8").get().then((item: any) => {
      console.log(item[0].ServerRelativeUrl);
    });
```

[image]